# Use dplyr to compute "streaks" in column of data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I dont think the title clearly explain the data calculation I need to do, so I have created a simple reproducible example below:

Here is the **input dataframe**

```
structure(list(homePoints = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5), awayPoints = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10), homeMargin = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -2, -2, 0, -3, -1, -4, -4, -4, -6, -6, -5
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

# A tibble: 18 x 3
   homePoints awayPoints homeMargin
        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1          0          0          0
 2          0          0          0
 3          0          0          0
 4          0          0          0
 5          0          0          0
 6          0          1         -1
 7          0          2         -2
 8          0          2         -2
 9          0          2         -2
10          2          2          0
11          2          5         -3
12          4          5         -1
13          4          8         -4
14          4          8         -4
15          4          8         -4
16          4         10         -6
17          4         10         -6
18          5         10         -5
```

And I'm simply attempting to get the following **output** of "home streaks":

```
c(-2, 2, -3, 2, -5, 1)
```

Output explained - The away team starts the game by scoring 2 points (separately 1 point at a time over rows 6 and 7) **`-2`**, then the home team scores 2 points (row 10) **`2`**, then the away team scores 3 points (row 11) **`-3`**, then the home team scores 2 points (row 12) **`2`**, then the away team scores 5 points (rows 13, 16) **`-5`**, then the home team scores 1 point (row 18), **`1`**. Positives for home streaks, negatives for away streaks.

Preferably these streaks would be created as a separate column onto the dataframe called `streaks` or something like that, and the dataframe would be filtered (in this instance from 18 to 6 rows), with no real preference as to which rows are lost.

I am actively working on this, but wanted to post here as I've been struggling a bit over the last bit of time on this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** a particular challenge is that I cannot simply look for changes in the homeMargin column, as a single change in the margin doesn't equal a streak. Rather, streaks involve a continuous change in the margin in the same direction.

**Edit2:** my efforts are something along these lines so far:

```
my_data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(streakDirection = c(0, diff(zoo::as.zoo(homeMargin), na.pad = F))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(signChange = c(0, diff(sign(streakDirection))))
```

...however this doesn't really get me to where I need to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
points %>%
  mutate(change_net = homeMargin - lag(homeMargin, default = 0),
         direction  = sign(change_net)) %>%
  filter(direction != 0) %>%
  mutate(streak = cumsum(direction != lag(direction, default = 0))) %>%
  count(streak, wt = change_net)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  streak     n
   <int> <dbl>
1      1    -2
2      2     2
3      3    -3
4      4     2
5      5    -5
6      6     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Same idea, a bit different implementation:

```r
my_data %>% 
      mutate(mdif = c(0 , (diff(homePoints) - diff(awayPoints))), 
             msgn=sign(mdif)) %>% 
      filter(mdif!=0) %>% 
      mutate(mgrp=cumsum((msgn!=lag(msgn, default = 0))))  %>%  
      group_by(mgrp)  %>% 
      summarise(mdif = sum(mdif)) %>% 
      pull(mdif)

#> [1] -2  2 -3  2 -5  1
```

Comment: yeah i actually did something like this in my code. `group_by` followed by `mutate` followed by a `filter` instead of using `count`